# Is it possible for 2 objects to be attached together but both objects are animated differently?

Tags: animation

In other words, I am designing a flag that's falling off a tower, and I want to make the cloth part of the flat ripple as it falls while it is attached to the pole which is also falling.

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually really simple. Just Parent your flag to your pole with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Use pinning in the cloth settings and use Rigid Bodies for the pole or just animate it.